# I need to display "Monday" with left justified and the highest columns appears in first row in descending order

Tags: c++, programming-languages

should be like this output:

Monday

onday

nday

day

ay

y

what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

`int main () {
    char *weekDays[7]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
        cout << weekDays[0][i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
    }`

output:

`M
o
n
d
a
y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im on mobile and tired but sth. like this should work:

```
int main(){recPrint(0);}

void recPrint(int level){
char mon[] = "Monday";
for(int i=level; i<strlen(mon); i++){
std::cout << mon[i];
} 
std::cout << std::endl;
recPrint(++level);
}
```

add another parameter char dayOfTheWeek[] and you can call it with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(char s[])
{
    int n = strlen(s);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << s[j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main () {
    char *weekDays[7]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"};

   display(weekDays[0]);
}
```